# How to stack & align label over the card

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I have a task to create a card with label on top of it. Able to get this with stack widget; however, am not sure how to align the top label properly similar to the `flutter debug label`.

[image]

Any tips to achieve this?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/rotated_corner_decoration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use the `Banner` widget for this.

Ex,

```
return ClipRect(
      child: Banner(
      message: "debug",
      location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Card(...)
);
```

Reference: https://flutter-widget.live/widgets/Banner

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top: -20,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        child: Container(width: 100, height: 20, color: Colors.red, child:Text('development'),),
        angle: radians(45),
      ),
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: Actually, have to position the red label `debug` in the tilted way;

Comment: The `Banner` widget does the work. Thanks for your help!